# Can we force IDE (i.e. Visual Studio Code) to load extensions AFTER it's loaded?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to FORCE i.e. Visual Studio Code, to load the extensions not that moment when it is loading (which causes to delay i.e. 1-2 seconds), but after the plain VS IDE is opened (like a newly installed) and when the text-editor area appears, only after that start loading of extensions. Thus, this will save us many  seconds everytime we open it!.

Do you have any such "workaround" or extension exist, which will do that trick?

Comment: Just manually start up one of the (heavier) extensions (There might be a command or you could assign a keyboard shortcut) and if you're lucky, the rest of the extensions will start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessary. VS Code loads and activates extensions lazily so they should not interfere with editor startup. See the [Extension Anatomy guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/extension-anatomy) and [this brief article](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/extension-host) about the extension host for an overview of how VS Code extensions are activated and executed.

A properly written html formatter extension for example should never be loaded or activated until you actually open an html file. And even if that extension is poorly written and activates as soon as you open VS Code, that should never slow down VS Code's startup itself because the extension will only be loaded and activated after the main VS Code editor starts up and because the extension will be run by a separate process (the extension host) from the main editor. In fact, even if an extension goes into an infinite loop as soon as it loads, the worst the extension could do is prevent other extensions from providing data to VS Code; the main editor UI should never freeze or slow down

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that loading extensions after starting would do any good, because you still would need to wait for them to load to start working. 
I was not able to find such an extensions, but a workaround could be writing an extension which disables all extensions on closing Visual Studio Code and enables them when after you start it. 
Even though after reading the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview) i am not sure it is possible.

Comment: thanks. yes, i was hoping if anyone can write such extension or make some workaround. I mean, after it's loaded without extensions and pure editor appears, then asynchronously other extension could have started.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible [see official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#onStartupFinished).

> Activation Events is a set of JSON declarations that you make in the activationEvents field of package.json Extension Manifest. Your extension becomes activated when the Activation Event happens.

#### onStartupFinished:

> This activation event is emitted and interested extensions will be activated some time after VS Code starts up. This is similar to the * activation event, but it will not slow down VS Code startup.

```json
"activationEvents": [
    "onStartupFinished"
]
```

Comment: This answer is for the extension writer.  The question is about a user trying to delay the startup of all extensions, not one that he has written.

Comment: @Mark And why is that? If extension is properly written (exported an activate() function from its main module) but it has "activationEvents" set to  "*" you can edit package.json and see if it works. I've done that to almost all of extensions on my setup and it works like a charm. If it is open source you can modify it.

Comment: @Mark would be nice if there was an extension, which could override that setting for other extensinos, without manually rewriting the "package.json" files.

Comment: @T.Todua  And check if the extension's package.json activation events have changed each time they upgrade.  The time spent doing that vs any possible start-up delay...

Comment: @Mark absolutely. There needs just to be a native (or by extension) option, saying "load extensions after VSC load", and the any extensions package.json's directive would be overrided by that setting. period. that would have been good.

Comment: If you have a low spec laptop like I do then you do what you can to make things works

Answer (score 0):

I've found out, that clicking `View > Command Palete` (or just <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+P</kbd>) and typing `Show Running Extensions` command, shows the **Activation time** for each extension. I've found that extensions doesn't take any time at all. It's probably VSCode app that takes much time to load.